# LuaTeX(ja), CJK-fonts: Which CJK font bundle should I use?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, cjk, luatexja

I have a question to the experts: 
Which CJK font bundle that is included in TeXLive 2020 should I use?

I would like a sans serif Japanese font and a serif font; a*nd if possible: a "ttfamily" font.*
If possible, everything with the same proportions.

I have found that *'msyahei.ttf'* (which is a sans serif CJK font) contains Kanji characters quite reliably.
*Is there anything comparable in TL2020?*

`mincho = ca. 'rmfamily'    |  gothic = ca. 'sffamily'`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of CJK OpenType/TrueType fonts included in TeX Live 2020.  You can search for these packages on CTAN.

- Japanese: haranoaji (OpenType), haranoaji-extra (OpenType), ipaex (TrueType)
- Chinese: arphic-ttf (TrueType), fandol (OpenType)
- Korean: unfonts-core (TrueType), unfonts-extra (TrueType), baekmuk (TrueType)

All of Kanji characters in these fonts have the same widths.

Answer (score 0):

Although you ask about fonts shipped with LaTeX, you can use any of the presets in `luatexja-preset`.

From the manual, the presets are

> haranoaji, hiragino-pro, hiragino-pron, ipa, ipa-hg, ipaex, ipaex-hg,kozuka-pr6, kozuka-pr6n, kozuka-pro, moga-mobo, moga-mobo-ex, bizud,morisawa-pr6n, morisawa-pro, ms, ms-hg, noembed, noto-otc, noto-otf,sourcehan, sourcehan-jp, ume, yu-osx, yu-win, yu-win10

You can instead load `luatexja-fontspec` and use `jfontspec` to load an arbitrary font with options.  You can also define new presets with `\ltjnewpreset`.

Also, if you load `ctex` and compile on LuaLaTeX, it will use `luatex-ja` as its backend and you will be able to `\setCJKmainfont[Script=Kana, Language=Japanese]`, `\setCJKmonofont[Script=Kana, Language=Japanese]`, etc.

There are a few Japanese fonts out there explicitly defined as fixed-width, such as Noto Sans Mono CJK JP.